# Downloading files from FTP server recursively from various sub directories

Tags: java, ftp, spring-integration, outbound

I have configured beans in an XML file with the inbound channel adapter with an OUTBOUND GATEWAY. I am using @serviceactivator in java class to invoke the channel.But m getting files which are in the root folder only am not able to get the files from the sub directories.

My XML file:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inbound1" expression="'/'">
 <int:poller fixed-delay="3000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGet"
        session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
        request-channel="inbound1"
        local-directory="C:/Users/pprakash/Desktop/DataFiles/actual"
        auto-startup="true"
        command="mget"
        command-options="-R"
        filename-pattern="*.csv"
        expression="'actual/*/*'"
        reply-channel="outbound"/>

<int:channel id="outbound">
<int:interceptors>
    <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
</int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" log-full-message="true" />

'<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
                  class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
            <property name="host" value="192.168.79.1"/>
            <property name="port" value="21"/>
            <property name="username" value="*****"/>
            <property name="password" value="*****"/>
            <property name="bufferSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>'
```

My java code is like :-

```
 static int index=0;
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inbound1")
public void foo1(File file) throws InterruptedException {
     logger.debug("Inbound msg to  gateway :[ "+(index++)+"]" +    file.getAbsolutePath());
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outbound")
public void foo2(List<File> file) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("outbound gateway");
   logger.debug("File Received  :[ "+(index++)+"]" + file.size());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filename-pattern="*.csv"`

Unless your subdirectories also match that pattern they won't be scanned.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway)

> For example, `filename-regex="(subDir|.*1.txt)"` will retrieve all files ending with `1.txt` in the remote directory and the subdirectory `subDir`. **If a subdirectory is filtered, no additional traversal of that subdirectory is performed.**

(My emphasis).

So, your pattern needs to be such that subdirectories in the tree will be traversed.

Comment: hello gary, my sub directories contains *.csv file...
its not traversing the sub directory.. its only traversing the file which are not in the sub directories..
like actual/abc/2016/ has some *.csv file
       actual/abc/ has *.csv file... then actual/abc/ *.csv is being downloaded only..

Comment: Right, but the directories themselves have to match the pattern - you need to make the patten (regex) something like `filename-regex="(actual|abc|*.csv)"` - otherwise `actual` and `abc` will be filtered out. Or, you can use a custom `FileListFilter` that ignores (does not filter) directories. We should probably add such a filter to the framework. I added a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4149).

Comment: yeah when i ignored the file-pattern then each file from every subdirectories is being downloaded . Thanks gary
if i needed only .csv file to be downloaded then?

if any new file is put into these sub Directories when server is up.. can we download those files also?

Comment: You can use a `CompositeFileListFilter` which can be configured with a `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` (and the regex filter) to ignore any files that have already been fetched and only fetch new ones.

Comment: hi Gary i found out one attritubute "MODE"  which can be used for preventing the duplicate  files or overwriting the files. Thanks gary :)
it was a 4-5 days continous bug.
thanks for the help :)